# Host port mapping not working with docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a node app that listens on port 8000, I containerized it using following Docker file

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "nodemon", "start" ]
```

My compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: node.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: console:cp
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

I have ensured the node app listens on all interfaces i.e. 0.0.0.0. But still whenever I type http://localhost:8000 it says this site cannot be reached.

When I run following inspect command to list all port bindings it returns: `8000/tcp -> 8000`

```
docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' a5c17883fd5c
```

Any ideas? I am pulling my hairs at the moment.

I am using `docker-compose up` command.

#### Versions

Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9

Mac 0SX 10.13.2

Comment: What version of docker for Mac are you using? Is it possible that your docker engine is running in a virtual machine instead of your localhost?

Comment: @whites11 here is my docker info: https://pasteboard.co/HbSO7dH.png also I think this problem started to happen when I updated my Docker recently. Before it was working fine.

Comment: Looks like you are using docker-machine. This means your docker Daemon is running inside a virtual machine, so you need to connect to that virtual machine's IP rather than localhost in order to reach your containers. Try running `docker-machine ls` in a terminal to check if I am right or not

Comment: @whites11 here is what it says: https://pasteboard.co/HbUf6gD.png

Comment: Ok my hypothesis was wrong. Have no clue then